Google Pay - recurring payments on Android via Adyen gateway
I'd like to set up the recurring payment via Google Pay on my backend. My gateway provider is Adyen. I already implemented working solution for 1-time payments. Google Pay documentation is clear about that.
However, what I can't seem to find is a way to implement the request for a recurring payments. Eg. what JSON to send to Google Pay to retrieve a "special" token for recurring payments. Or at least that was my thinking that there is a special token for that.
I checked adyen docs, but there is nothing on how to implement this on Google Pay side.
I read this and this here on SO, but I am stil not more clever on what I have to actually send to Google Pay.
TLDR: Do I create payment request for $0 and use the returned token with adyen for subsequent recurring payments? Or is there something more special for recurring payments to work?

Making recurring payments with GooglePay (and other payment methods) involves 3 steps:

create the token making an initial payment (if you are just validating the payment details it is possible to use an amount of 0 - it is called zero-auth transaction) by invoking the Checkout API /payments endpoint.
obtain the token processing the RECURRING_CONTRACT webhoook. You could also attempt to get the token from the response of the /payments endpoint, however this is not always possible. See the details here.
make a payment passing the token in the paymentMethod.storedPaymentMethodId field

     {
       "amount":{
          "value":2000,
          "currency":"USD"
       },
       "paymentMethod":{
          "type":"googlepay",
          "storedPaymentMethodId":"M5N7TQ4TG5PFWR50"
       },
       "reference":"YOUR_ORDER_REFERENCE",
       "shopperInteraction": "ContAuth",
       "recurringProcessingModel": "Subscription",
       "merchantAccount":"YOUR_MERCHANT_ACCOUNT",
       "shopperReference":"YOUR_SHOPPER_REFERENCE"
      }

Make sure the shopperReference is unique per shopper and it is the same one used in the request to create the token.

Thanks a lot! That first step info is crucial for me, because it was the only "blind step". I also found out that I can send request to Google pay without amount altogether, with totalPriceStatus = NOT_CURRENTLY_KNOWN and it seems to be working the same way.
